# can't get an element from not empty array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, firebase, object

I am getting an issue that is making my head explode.
I got an array of objects all of the same type.
When I console.log it I get an array that seems empty but contains 3 elements :

[image]

then problem is that I can't .filter it, you can see that the first element is undefined on the same console.log.

Thank you for your time, I have already used all the knowledge I have ...

Here is  the code I use to create the array :
get in firebase :

export const fetchCross = async (
currentUserId: string,
currentStudentId: string
) => {
const db = Firebase.firestore()
const querySnapshot = await db
.collection('users')
.doc(currentUserId)
.collection('eleves')
.doc(currentStudentId)
.collection('crosses')
.get()

```
const data = [] as firebase.firestore.DocumentData[]

querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => 
data.push(doc.data()))

return data
}


export const fetchCross = async (
    currentUserId: string,
    currentStudentId: string
) => {
    const db = Firebase.firestore()
    const querySnapshot = await db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(currentUserId)
        .collection('eleves')
        .doc(currentStudentId)
        .collection('crosses')
        .get()

    const data = [] as firebase.firestore.DocumentData[]

    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => 
    data.push(doc.data()))

    return data
}
```

use custom hook :

```
 export const useCrosses = (currentUserId: string, 
 allStudentsIds: string[]) => {
    const [crosses, setCrosses] = useState<{ id: string, docs: firebase.firestore.DocumentData[] }[]>()

useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
        setCrosses(await fetchCrosses(currentUserId, 
allStudentsIds))
    }
    fetch()

}, [currentUserId, allStudentsIds])

const refreshCrosses = async () => {
    setCrosses(await fetchCrosses(currentUserId, 
 allStudentsIds))
}

return { crosses, refreshCrosses }
}
```

Comment: Alex, could you provide some code of the creation for this array? Its hard to help you without any leads.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem. My guess is that it's an issue caused by asynchronous loading, but seeing the code will make that clear.

Comment: I added some code to my issue, sorry i am a begginer.